# Consolibyte | PHP Dev Kit | Missing fields of customers in database table

Tags: quickbooks

We are using Consolibyte library to sync data of "customer","item" and "invoice" between QuickBooks Desktop and MySQL.
As per our investigation, Customers fields mentioned in following screenshot are not found in database. 
Can you please confirm that Consolibyte does not sync these field?

[image: Customers fields not found in database]

Second question is that we want to sync data of multiple companies with MySQL. Does Consolibyte create separate database for each company or single database can be used to sync data of multiple companies?